# Value of $P(-1)$ of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

If $P(x^3 - x^2) = x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x$, compute $P(-1)$.

I can't do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial, I'm having a hard time believing that $P(x^3-x^2)$ is a 7th degree polynomial. Or that it has a linear term.

Comment: Hint: what is the remainder if you divide $P(x^3-x^2)$ by $x^3-x^2+1$?

Comment: This makes no sense. If you let $x=0$, you get $P(0)=0$. If you let $x=1$, you get $P(0) = 8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us keep reducing the polynomial by $x^3=x^2-1$, then $$P(-1)=x(x^2-1)^2+(x^2-1)^2+x^2(x^2-1)+ (x^2-1)+2x^2+2x=x^3-x^2=-1$$